# VBA Dependent Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 combo boxes which are dependent with each other. List on cmb2 depends on the value on cmb1. cmb3 list depends on cmb2 value.

My problem is, when I remove/delete the values on all combo boxes, when I click cmb2, it still shows the list of the last value chosen on cmb1 & same goes with cmb3.

What's the code to show it empty if the combo box where it's dependent to doesn't have any value?

Comment: you need to create subroutines to check for values, then update the existing cmb based on the results of the check.

Perhaps an On-Change event.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I think based on added information in the comment that you should look to encapsulate the logic in sub procedures and functions. To best do so, there should be some logic between named ranges and the values in the combobox.

In the below example, I created a function to handle conversions from the value in the independent combobox and the named ranges. You can supply your own connector, but I assumed that any space will be changed to an underscore (so, 'Account Information' will be replaced with 'Account_Information').

Next a subprocedure checks to confirm that the named range exists in the workbook that matches the converted value in the independent combobox. If so, the dependent box takes on that named range as its `List` property. If not, the dependent combobox is cleared.

The benefit to using this type of a system is that it could be repeated for other comboboxes without rewriting code. See below code and let us know if you need added help.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With Me.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Account Information"
        .AddItem "Other Stuff"
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With Me
        LoadDependentCBO Me.ComboBox1, Me.ComboBox2
    End With
End Sub

Private Function ConvertValueToNamedRange(sValue As String, sConnector As String) As String
    'This function takes values in the combobox and converts them to named ranges
    'The spaces are replaced with whichever connector is supplied to the function
    'NOTE: I created a separate function even though this only uses a built-in function
    'in case more implementation code is needed

    ConvertValueToNamedRange = Replace(sValue, " ", sConnector)
End Function

Private Sub LoadDependentCBO(cboIndependent As ComboBox, cboDependent As ComboBox)
    'This code looks to see if there is a match between the value of the independent combobox
    'and a named range in the workbook. If not, the dependent combobox is set to be empty

    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim rNamedRange As Range

    sTemp = ""
    On Error Resume Next
        sTemp = Names.Item(ConvertValueToNamedRange(cboIndependent.Value, "_")).Name
    On Error GoTo 0

    If sTemp = "" Then
        'There is no matching named range so clear the dependent combobox
        cboDependent.Clear
    Else
        cboDependent.List = Range(sTemp).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

---

OLD POST:
The code `ComboBox1.ListIndex = -1` will set the combo box to empty (change the name of the box to suit). The logic to do so depends on more details. Let us know if you need help with implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure where to put that code, though :( Here's my code: 
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
With Me
    Select Case .ComboBox1.Value
    Case "Account Information": .ComboBox2.List = Sheet1.Range("Account_Information").Value
   End Select
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
With Me
    Select Case .ComboBox2
    Case "Update Account Information": .ComboBox3.List = Sheet1.Range("UpdateCustomerInformation").Value
    End Select
End With
End Sub

Comment: @Meedee  See my update above and let me know if this works better for you.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! Now, I just have to figure out how to do it on the other comboboxes. Again, thank you so much for your help

Comment: @Meedee You can actually reuse the code in the `Click` event of the other comboboxes and just change the independent and dependent combo box. So, for example if combobox3's list property depends on combobox 2, then the code would read `LoadDependentCBO me.ComboBox2, me.ComboBox3`